# How to create a matrix without a loop

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I would like to know if it is possible to create a matrix without writing any loop. I try to start with a simple list of range but I don't know how to go further.

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 4).ToList()
```

Here the code with 3 loops :

```
    private static int[][] calculPossibleCombinaison(){
    int l;
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < 5; j++) {
            for (int k = 1; k < 5; k++) {
                l = (i*j*k)-1;
                combinaison[l][0] = i;
                combinaison[l][1] = j;
                combinaison[l][2] = k;
                console.writeline("["+combinaison[l][0]+","+combinaison[l][1]+","+combinaison[l][2]+"]");
            }
        }
    }
    return combinaison;
}
```

This is the result of my matrix

> ```
> [1,1,1]
> [1,1,2]
> [1,1,3]
> [1,2,1]
> [1,2,2]
> [1,2,3]
> [1,3,1]
> [1,3,2]
> [1,3,3]
> [2,1,1]
> [2,1,2]
> [2,1,3]
> [2,2,1]
> [2,2,2]
> [2,2,3]
> [2,3,1]
> [2,3,2]
> [2,3,3]
> [3,1,1]
> [3,1,2]
> [3,1,3]
> [3,2,1]
> [3,2,2]
> [3,2,3]
> [3,3,1]
> [3,3,2]
> [3,3,3]
> ```

Do you think it's possible ?

Thx a lot

Comment: you need to use linq or lambda expression for it Check these link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183626/convert-nested-for-loops-into-single-linq-statement;
http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/105336/convert-foreach-loop-into-linq-in-c

Comment: What is the point of avoiding loops? Even with Linq you´d use them internally. There is no way on going through all the cells without iterating the list/matrix/whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 3)
.SelectMany(x => Enumerable.Range(1, 3), (x, y) => new[] {x, y})    
.SelectMany(x => Enumerable.Range(1, 3), (x, y) => new[] {x[0], x[1], y}).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use LINQ instead of for loops but still you can get rid of loops. using Linq is cool but it has loop implantation inside it. as if you put those for loops inside a function and then call it. 
It can't be done without loops.

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 4).ToList().ForEach(i=>{
      Enumerable.Range(1, 4).ToList().ForEach(j=>{
             Enumerable.Range(1, 4).ToList().ForEach(k=>{
                    l = (i*j*k)-1;
                combinaison[l][0] = i;
                combinaison[l][1] = j;
                combinaison[l][2] = k;
            });
      });
});
```

Recursive:

```
int i=0,j=0,k=0;

    public void MakeMartix(){

         if(i>3){i=0;j++;}
         if(j>3){j=0;k++;}
         if(k>4)return;
         l = (i*j*k)-1;
         combinaison[l][0] = i;
         combinaison[l][1] = j;
         combinaison[l][2] = k;
              i++;
              MakeMatirx();
    }
```

Comment: Can it be done with link or something else and how? I would like to have one line for that like Enumerable.Range(1, 4).ToList()

Comment: It can but as I said its like hiding the loops and not, not using them

Comment: Do you know how to do it? because I do not. And I know it's like hidding them.

Comment: @stix I added a recursive version code. have a look at it.

Comment: Thx but this is not what I asked. Look the answer of @tym32167